# Provider State Management implementation. Putting a function in create: property

Tags: flutter, dart

I am completely lost in State Management field. Tried multiple tutorials, articles, even looked at Github similar projects. No idea how to implement provider in my Weather app.

```
class WeatherMainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: kBackgroundColor,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: ChangeNotifierProvider<WeatherModel>(
          create: (context) => ApiCall().getWeather('New York'),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: 30,
                  top: 15,
                  left: 30,
                  right: 30,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          'Today 28. apr',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: kAccentColor,
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            MenuSearchButton(
                              boxSize: 60,
                              onPressed: () => print('search prssed'),
                              content: Icon(
                                Icons.search,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                size: 30,
                              ),
                            ),
                            MenuSearchButton(
                              boxSize: 60,
                              onPressed: () => print('menu pressed'),
                              content: Icon(
                                Icons.menu,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                size: 30,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            '12',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 100,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.cloud,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  size: 25.0,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 15.0),
                                Text(
                                  'Raining',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: 30,
                      top: 15,
                      left: 60,
                      right: 60,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'Put on your coat, and don\'t forget the umbrella.',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 25,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: kAccentColor,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: 30,
                      top: 15,
                      left: 30,
                      right: 30,
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        DetailedCard(
                          header: 'HUMIDITY',
                          headerColor: kAccentColor,
                          text: '87%',
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        DetailedCard(
                          header: 'WIND M/S',
                          headerColor: kAccentColor,
                          text: '4,1',
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        DetailedCard(
                          header: 'FEELS LIKE',
                          headerColor: kAccentColor,
                          text: '18',
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So I have a model class WeatherModel its basically empty, contains only constructors for the weather info. ApiCall class is where all the networking happens and it returns WeatherModel object filled with data. But with ChangeNotifier like this I get error:
'The return type 'Future' isn't a 'WeatherModel', as defined by anonymous closure.'

I read that ChangeNotifierProvider should receive only a Object in create, while I'am passing it a function. But I dont know where else to call that getWeather function? Completely lost.

Edit:

ApiCall.dart

```
class ApiCall extends ChangeNotifier{
  Future<WeatherModel> getWeather(String cityName) async {
    String url =
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$cityName&appid=$apikey';
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var weatherData = jsonDecode(response.body);

      return WeatherModel(
        temp: weatherData['main']['temp'] - 273.15,
        feelsLike: weatherData['main']['temp'] - 273.15,
        condition: weatherData['weather'][0]['main'],
        humidity: weatherData['main']['humidity'],
        windSpeed: weatherData['wind']['speed'],
      );
    } else {
      throw Exception('Ooops something went wrong');
    }
  }
}
```

WeatherModel.dart

```
class WeatherModel{
  final double temp;
  final double windSpeed;
  final int feelsLike;
  final int humidity;
  final String condition;

  WeatherModel({
    this.temp,
    this.windSpeed,
    this.feelsLike,
    this.humidity,
    this.condition,
  });
}
```

Comment: can you add model and ApiCall class?

Comment: Done. check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several change which you should make to work your code.

Change following line

```
    child: ChangeNotifierProvider<WeatherModel>(
```

To

```
    child: ChangeNotifierProvider< ApiCall >(
```

You have to provide class name which extends ChangeNotifier.

You have to call notifyListeners() at the end of method, on which call you want to change data.

```
  else {
      throw Exception('Ooops something went wrong');
    }
    notifyListeners();  // added line
  }
```

getWeather should not return any value. Instead of that you can create any WeatherModel object in ApiCall class and update it in that method and access that object wherever you want to use that data.

Update:

```
 child: ChangeNotifierProvider<ApiCalll>( create: (context) => ApiCall()
```

You can call this method in following way.

```
Provider.of<ApiCall>(context).getWeather('New York');
```

Comment: child: ChangeNotifierProvider<ApiCalll>(
          create: (context) => ApiCall().getWeather('New York'),                                                           Where am I supposed to call getWeather? Still not working like this since getWeather is now void. I also added this line: final appState = Provider.of<ApiCall>(context); so I should go to Text widget and set it to appState.weatherModel.temp for example. But I cant get to weather model which is filled (but not returned) inside getWeather function.